# Solution for Master fails in solr

Tags: solr, solrj, solrcloud, sunspot-solr

As it is a architecture for solr. Is there any solution if Master fails ??
As we take master for indexing and user can query on salves. should we include more master?

[Click to view the image of Solr Architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9KJf.jpg)

Comment: Could you explain what do you mean for "if Master fails"?

Comment: If master server fails means if it stop working by any faults

Comment: any faults is too generic.

Comment: if failure in indexing ?